# How to test a event has been registered in AssertWasCalled(AAA) way?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a service class and an action class, and the action happens when event triggered. 
So test register the event in service class is kind of important.

I tried to use Rhino Mock test RegisterEvent function, but I can not make test pass, AssertWasCalled always fails.

I will appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance or articles links.

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    public ActionClass Printer {set; get;}
    public void RegisterEvent()
    {
        Printer = new ActionClass ();
        Printer.PrintPage += Printer.ActionClass_PrintPage;
    }
}
public class ActionClass
{
    event PrintPageEventHandler PrintPage;
    public void ActionClass_OnAction( object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e )
    {
        // Action here.
    }
}
[Test]
public void RegisterEvent_Test()
{
    var service = new ServiceClass();

    var mockActionClass = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IActionClass>();

    service.Printer = mockActionClass;
    service.RegisterEvent();
    mockActionClass.AssertWasCalled( x => x.PrintPage += Arg<PrintPageEventHandler>.Is.Anything );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies elsewhere - in `RegisterEvent` you create new instance of `ActionClass` which overwrites mocked one set in test. To make test pass you simply need to remove that instantiation line from `RegisterEvent`:

```
public void RegisterEvent()
{
    // This overrides mock you set in test
    // Printer = new ActionClass ();
    Printer.PrintPage += Printer.ActionClass_PrintPage;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. @srsyogesh mentioned that as well. However, the Arg<> need to change in the test function as well to make it work. I will post my result.

Comment: Found out at the end, there was something else jammed up in the testing, so Arg<> does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Arg<EventHandler>.Is.Anything
```

to

```
Arg<EventHandler<YourEventArgTypeName>>.Is.Anything
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried that already. But it can't build. Error is EventHandler<PrintPageEventHandler> is not assignable to parameter PrintPageEventHandler.

Comment: Oops . Can you share your delegate definition ?

Comment: Also one problem i could see from code is you are assigning the Printer property to Printer = new ActionClass (); in RegisterEventClass which will reinitialize the Printer property (i.e though you set the mocked object it will reinitialize , x.PrintPage and Printer.PrintPage in these statements the objects are not same). So please remove that line your test will pass

Comment: Btw, this is the delegate.    public delegate void PrintPageEventHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e);

Comment: then you have to do two things , 
1.remove the creation of new instance in RegisterEvent method and 2.change the statement in your test code as mockActionClass.AssertWasCalled( x => x.PrintPage += Arg<PrintPageEventHandler<PrintePageEventArgs>>.Is.Anything );

Comment: Thanks, removing creation of new instance definitely helped, but Arg<PrintPageEventHandler<PrintePageEventArgs>> can not compile. I managed to get it working, and have put my working solution at the bottom, it just I still don't understand why I can't use Arg<>.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31872/discussion-between-srsyogesh-and-winter-winter)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jimmy_keen spotted my mistake, and now there are two working assertion.

This is a working solution...

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    public IActionClass Printer {set; get;}
    public void RegisterEvent()
    {
        Printer.PrintPage += ActionClass_PrintPage;
    }
}
public class ActionClass : IActionClass 
{
    event PrintPageEventHandler PrintPage;
    public void ActionClass_PrintPage( object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e )
    {
        // Action here.
    }
}
[Test]
public void RegisterEvent_Test()
{
    var service = new ServiceClass();

    var mockActionClass = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IActionClass>();

    service.Printer = mockActionClass;
    service.RegisterEvent();
    mockActionClass.AssertWasCalled(x => x.PrintPage += Arg<PrintPageEventHandler>.Is.Anything); // This does work. Credit to @jimmy_keen
    //mockActionClass.AssertWasCalled(x => x.PrintPage += Arg<EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>>.Is.Anything); // Can not compile.
    mockActionClass.AssertWasCalled(x => x.PrintPage += x.ActionClass_PrintPage); // This works.
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile - why is `ServiceClass.Printer` property of `ActionClass` type **and not** `IActionClass` (interface)? If you're mocking classes, Rhino usually won't  help you much with assertions/verifications.

Comment: @jimmy_keen thanks for spotting it out, it was a typo. It should be IActionClass.

Comment: you sure you checked your code correctly? I tested it (http://pastebin.com/77Nfsx5j) and your first assertion (*"Do not work"*) **does work**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spotting that and gone through all the way. I created a sample project as well, and it works, found out at the end there is another thing jammed up the code caused the problem. So yes, the first assertion works.